# How to get GET parameter?

Tags: powershell, http

I was successfully able to open a port on my computer (using only PowerShell) and know when HTTP requests are done to that port. I came up with this simple code:

```
$listener = [System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener]5566;
$listener.Start();

while ($true) {
    $client = $Listener.AcceptTcpClient();
    Write-Host "Connected!";

    $client.Close();
}
```

If I open my browser and type `http://localhost:5566` in the PowerShell interface it will show a message that a user got connected.

What I need to do is to get the GET parameters of this HTTP request. For example, if instead I had opened my browser and typed `http://localhost:5566/test.html?parameter1=xxx&parameter2=yyy`.

How can I grab the GET parameters (parameter1 and parameter2) name and values using my simplified code above?

Comment: The first line you receive will be `GET /test.html?parameter1=xxx&parameter2=yyy HTTP/1.0` so you can parse the parameters from the string

Comment: The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.accepttcpclient.aspx) has sample code. Translating the C# code to PowerShell is trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are comfortable using the HttpListener instead of the TcpListener. It's easier to do the job.

Below script will output in a browser

```
Path is /test.html
parameter2 is equal to yyy
parameter1 is equal to xxx
```

Quick and dirty script

```
$listener = New-Object System.Net.HttpListener
$listener.Prefixes.Add("http://localhost:5566/")


try {
    $listener.Start();
    while ($true) {   
        $context = $listener.GetContext()
        $request = $context.Request

        # Output the request to host
        Write-Host $request | fl * | Out-String

        # Parse Parameters from url
        $rawUrl = $request.RawUrl

        $Parameters = @{}
        $rawUrl = $rawUrl.Split("?")
        $Path = $rawUrl[0]
        $rawParameters = $rawUrl[1]
        if ($rawParameters) {
            $rawParameters = $rawParameters.Split("&")


            foreach ($rawParameter in $rawParameters) {
                $Parameter = $rawParameter.Split("=")

                $Parameters.Add($Parameter[0], $Parameter[1])
            }
        }

        # Create output string (dirty html)
        $output = "<html><body><p>"
        $output = $output + "Path is $Path" + "<br />"
        foreach ($Parameter in $Parameters.GetEnumerator()) {
            $output = $output + "$($Parameter.Name) is equal to $($Parameter.Value)" + "<br />"
        }

        $output = $output + "</p></body></html>"
        # Send response
        $statusCode = 200
        $response = $context.Response
        $response.StatusCode = $statusCode    
        $buffer = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($output)
        $response.ContentLength64 = $buffer.Length
        $output = $response.OutputStream
        $output.Write($buffer,0,$buffer.Length)
        $output.Close()
    }
} finally {
    $listener.Stop()
}
```

Cheers 
Glenn

Comment: It didnt work my friend, I save the code you gave me in a file test.ps1 and executed it. Then I opened my browser and accesses localhost:5566 and nothing happened.

Comment: **slap on the head**, yeah, I did not check without parameters... I've changed it accordingly.

Comment: Why parse query string? It is already parsed. Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httplistenerrequest.querystring?view=net-6.0